# Vue.set - wrong type inferred by TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I create a Vuex module an in my mutation I set an object to another object using a key: obj[key] = newobj. Also I use typescript here.

Given:

```
// store state interface
export interface Office {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    zip?: string;
    city?: string;
    address?: string;
    phone?: string;
    phone2?: string;
}

export interface Organization {
    [key: string]: any;

    id: number;
    name: string;
    offices: { [key: string]: Office };
}

// store action
const setOffice = (state: OrganizationState, item: Office) => {
    Vue.set<Office>(state.offices, item.id, item);
    // or, it does not change much
    Vue.set(state.offices, item.id, item);
};
```

TypeScript gives me an error:

```
25:19 Argument of type '{ [key: string]: Office; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Office[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: Office; }'.

    23 | 
    24 | const setOffice = (state: OrganizationState, item: Office) =>{
  > 25 |     Vue.set<Office>(state.offices, item.id, item);
       |                   ^
    26 | };
```

[image]

In typings there are 2 versions of Vue.set - one for object, one for array:

```
// vue/types/vue.d.ts
export interface VueConstructor<V extends Vue = Vue> {
    set<T>(object: object, key: string, value: T): T;
    set<T>(array: T[], key: number, value: T): T;
}
```

In my case, it always uses type *array*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your second parameter (`item.id`) is a number and this makes the call incompatible with the first overload which expects a `string` as the second argument.

The simple solution is to convert the `id` to a `string` in the call:

```
Vue.set<Office>(state.offices, item.id.toString(), item);
```